# 2 color theorem proof, straight lines inside a box

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, coloring

How can I prove mathematically that a box with $x$ straight lines drawn through it, can be colored with only 2 colors.

Comment: by box with $x$ straight lines drawn through it do you mean a grid graph?

Comment: Try generalizing: take a convex set, and show that if you draw a line through it, you can color that with two colors. Then use induction.

Comment: @Noah Deng: Induction on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have finite number of $x$ lines, you can come up with a direction of a new line $X$ what is not one of the $x$ directions.

With that line $X$ scroll through the box, and iterate the color each time you cross a line.